# RESOLVED cakephp 4 - Test mail in command

Tags: cakephp

How can I test that a mail sent in a command is correct ?

I have a testcase for the command, but I cannot use : https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/email.html#testing-mailers.

I use cake 4.3.4

The test case is:

```
    use EmailTrait;
    /**
     * Test execute method
     *
     * @return void
     * @uses \App\Command\NextweekCommand::execute()
     */
    public function testExecute(): void
    {
        $this->exec('nextweek');
        $this->assertMailSentTo('dype@localhost');
    }
```

And in the nextweek command, the mail is sent by:

```
                $email = new Mailer();

                $email->setViewVars([
                    'saison' => date("Y", strtotime('next Saturday')),
                    'titre' => $titre,
                    'evenements' => $evenements,
                    'resultats' => $resultats,
                    'domaine' => $this->domaine,
                    'ecoles' => $ecoles,
                    'statSite' => $statSite
                ]);

                $email
                    ->setFrom([$this->myconf['listediffasso'] => 'ASSO'])
                    ->setReplyTo([$this->myconf['listediffasso'] => 'ASSO'])

                    ->setTo($this->myconf['listediffasso'])
                    ->setSubject('Next week ')
                    ->setEmailFormat('html')
                    ->viewBuilder()
                    ->setTemplate('nextweek')
                    ->setLayout('asso1');

                $dest = $this->Users->getUserMailSynthese();
                foreach ($dest as $d) {
                    $email->addCc($d->email);
                }

                $email->deliver();
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "_I cannot use_"? How is your command sending mails?

Comment: I've added the email part of the command

Comment: Sorry, I've test it again and it works ! 
$this->assertMailSentTo('dype@localhost'); is TRUE !

Comment: to be more precise, I had 2 problems, a fixture was missing in the testcase and a fixture constant was not correct ...